# git push stuck at %100. But no error occur

Tags: git, github, version-control

Im trying to push my repository to git.
My remote and branch have correct point to remote address.
I tried to following.

```
git add * 
git commit -m "..."
git push origin main
```

After that, the terminal output is as follows;

```
Enumerating objects: 280, done.
Counting objects: 100% (280/280), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (266/266), done.
Writing objects: 100% (279/279), 3.63 MiB | 777.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 279 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

And process stuck at this point. There are no errors or something. I'm tried to pushing with create a new repository but process stuck at the same and nothing pushed to repository.
Why does this problem occur?

Comment: Try `GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin main` or `strace git push origin main`. The logs could be helpful.

Comment: 1 ===> exec-cmd.c:139          trace: resolved executable path from Darwin stack: <Path>            2 ===> exec-cmd.c:238          trace: resolved executable dir:  <Path>          3 ===>  git.c:460   trace: built-in: git pack-objects --all-progress-implied --revs --stdout --thin --delta-base-offset --progress                                                                                last 3 backtrace like this but still i did not understand

Comment: It seems stuck at `git pack-objects`. Try `git gc --force` first and then `git push origin main` again.

Comment: It was stack at the same point and im cancel the process with CTRL + C than i check my git repo and it's done!!!! Thanks a lot for guide.